# Excel Macro to recognize what day of the week today is

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create a macro that will look at what day of the week today is (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.) and if the day is a saturday or a sunday then the macro will just stop everything but if it is a weekday (M,T,W,Th,or F) then it will call the next Sub.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    **If today is Saturday or Sunday Then**
        **do nothing**
        Else
        Call Populate_Workbook()
      End If
End Sub
```

the parts with the ** are the parts that I need help figuring out. If someone ends up figuring this out, can you explain how you came up with the solution? Trying to learn and understand macros more.

Comment: @brettdj This question is actually the inverse of the one you pointed to. At any rate, all three answers there include unneeded extra statements or function calls.

Comment: It is the same question in determining whether the date falls on the weekend or a weekday. Your answer is better than the other ones presented.

Comment: @brettdj I'm just trying to understand. If the answers there are less helpful, why point readers of this question there? I think the average user would assume they are being told to ignore this page and go to the other page to get the best answer to this question. This seems counterproductive to me.

Comment: @ExcelHero My view is you should add your post to the other thread so there is a single reference for the question. The other question has three answers and 30K views, this one has one answer 50 views - even adjusting for the relative time these questions has been open leaves the other one as having 10 times the exposure rate. I can see why this might be frustrating as your answer is better, but it is more about not having the same questions existing in multiple places.

Comment: @brettdj OK. So I added my answer to that other question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) < 6 Then Populate_Workbook
End Sub
```

The Weekday() function has an optional 2nd parameter that tells it which day of the week the week starts on. The Weekday() function returns an integer from 1 through 7.

I've instructed it to start the week on MONDAY and so SATURDAY would be 6 and SUNDAY would be 7.

Comment: So if I change the "<6" to "=1" then would that say that if today is monday then populate_workbook?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.